# RegExp: Match all comments that don't end with period

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to find all the commented lines that don't end with period`(.)`.

I have this expression `//[A-Za-z0-9-\(\)\.,\-\\/ !\:_"]` but I don't know how to make it detect only lines that don't have periond`(.)` before EOL.

I'm using C++ so comments start with `//`. For example I want this string to be matched:

> // My comment here

but not this one:

> // My comment here.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What language are you using ? And could you provide some input and expected output ?

Comment: I'm using C++, sorry for not mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for negative lookbehind or lookahead, keep it simple:

```
^\/\/(.*[^.])$
        \    /
         \  /
          \/
           `-- This is the key, match any non-period character at the end.
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/JZb3RehqrR

As anubhava pointed out in the comment, the above regex does not capture empty comment lines. If you wish to also capture the empty comment lines, you can add a `?` to make the comment optional:

```
^\/\/(.*[^.])?$
             ^
             |
             `-- Added this in order to make the comment optional
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/INyArTf9qQ

Comment: Unfortunately it won't match match just `//` as you can see in:  http://rubular.com/r/rcQmtAQrK4

Comment: If that is a requirement, one could simply add a `?` behind the parenthesis: http://rubular.com/r/INyArTf9qQ -- Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This negative lookbehind based regex should work for you:

```
(?m)^//.*$(?<!\.)
```

OR negative lookahead based:

```
(?m)^//(?!.*\.$).*$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/sUHNDokY2j

Comment: (You probably want to use the `(?m)` modifier so the regex works on single lines.) Also, the `$` in the lookbehind assertion isn't necessary; neither is the `?` in the lookahead.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for your suggestions but just curious if that  wouldn't be the default behavior of dot `.` to not to match new line and work on single lines only?

Comment: Yes, the dot only works on single lines (and the `(?s)` modifier would change that), but `^` and `$` don't without the `(?m)` modifier.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Alright made an edit as per your suggestion. Thanks so much.